# Что выбрать: «эээ» или «э-э-э»?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

Допустим, человек закричал или задумался перед ответом. Как это можно отобразить на письме? Существует ли определённое правило на этот счёт: писать с дефисами или нет? У разных авторов видел и первый, и второй случаи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Можно с дефисом, можно и без — выбор той или иной конструкции не противоречит правилам, а зависит только от замысла автора.

> **3.** В любых текстах (чаще в художественных и публицистических) дефис может использоваться в выразительных целях:
> **а)** для выделения (смыслового и произносительного) какой-либо части слова...
> **б)** для передачи произношения по слогам с разными целями (произнесение говорящим незнакомого слова, смысловое выделение важного слова и др.)...
> **в)** для передачи протяжного звучания гласных, раскатистого ***р*** и других особенностей произношения...

• Примеры из Нацкорпуса

*— **Эээ...** — сочувственно протянул небритый; Судя по тому, что творилось на земле с момента ее... **эээ...** сотворения, богу свойственна только одна любовь — он любит разнообразные интересные истории* (Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033).

*Завидя жертву, заторможенно выдавливал: «**Эээ**, постой!»...* (Михаил Тарковский. Фундамент).
*— **Эээ**, — говорю я, — вот вы как всех облапошили* (Булат Окуджава. Новенький как с иголочки).

*— **Э-эээ!**.. Да он совсем больной* (Вадим Громов. Компромат для олигарха).

*— Ой, простите! — встрепенулся я и стукнулся своим стаканом о стакан соседки: — 3a ваше здоровье, **э-э-э...*** (Виктор Астафьев. Веселый солдат).
***Э-э-э**, Сали-и-им! — натужно завопил в ухо какой-то чернявый потный человек* (Андрей Волос. Недвижимость).
*— **Э-э-э**, — протянул пенсионер с лукавым торжеством и покачнул розовой головой* (Фазиль Искандер. Летним днем).
*Это пространство будет все время меняться. Оно зависит от... **э-э-э...** — Кармы? — подсказал Кедаев* (Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло).
*— **Э-э-э!** — тотчас закричали чеченцы. — Куда поехал?* (Дмитрий Линчевский. Враг).

[Дефис](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59#pp59) (ПАС)

Comment: @АнатолийТумбочка Анатолий (надеюсь, можно просто по имени), вас чем-то не устроил мой ответ? Вы ведь не посчитали его *полезным* — значит, что-то осталось не совсем понятным? Вот ещё, сравните: *— **Ммм…** Не люблю дорожную полицию* (Д. Рубина); *— Да, **м-м-м...** — замыкал было Кемал, но довольно быстро нашел колею рассказа и двинулся дальше* (Ф. Искандер).